# How to ensure a Screen reader announces capital letters

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

I'm working on an email that is sent out to customers. The email has an access code that is a mix of Upper and Lower case letters. The problem we are facing is that even with the setting on for reading capital letters as Cap the screen reader does not announce the case of the letters and reads them in a continuous flow. For example, we want it to read the following:

> Your one-time access code: U8dFyX

How do I make sure that it says that U, F, X are capital letters?

Comment: Why not just add a hidden `span` with literal `Capital` word in it? It will not be visible but the voice over will read it: `<span style="font-size: 0px;"> Capital </span>U`

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule you should not try to influence how a screen reader pronounces things. (@QuentinC has covered this in detail)

However in user testing we found that less experienced screen reader users struggled differentiating between letters by pitch (especially elderly screen reader users who also had a slight hearing impairment).

What we implemented was as follows:-

1. Display the activation code as normal.
2. After the activation code have a visually hidden section.
3. In this section we put 'for clarity your code contains upper and lower case letters as follows:'
4. We then added each letter to a span that explains what the letter is.

e.g.

```
<div class="visually-hidden">
    <p>for clarity your code contains upper and lower case letters as follows:</p>
    <span>Upper Case U</span><span>Number 8</span><span>Lower Case D</span> // etc.
</div>
```

It improved accuracy and recognition for everyone, even more experienced screen reader users benefited in a simulated noisy environment.

There is a problem with this that we eventually worked around.

The site was translated into multiple languages, so we had to translate 'Upper Case' and 'Lower Case' as part of `i18n` as it was causing confusion.

We eventually switched to a longer string of lower case characters only and made it case insensitive. (8 lower case characters is better than 6 alphanumeric characters anyway 208,827,064,576 combinations vs 68,719,476,736 combinations)

As **email isn't secure** it didn't really matter for anything other than reducing brute force attempts. If you are using it for security then stop!

### A better solution

We replaced the above solution after around a year.

Instead we just sent a link within the email that automatically entered the code.

As you mentioned it is a one use code, just apply the same logic to a single use link. `yoursite.com/code/aU4383H483kdj483Jfdfsk3UF`

This way you can have a 256 bit code if you want.

It has the added benefit of not reading an access code out-loud in a public space.

As access codes do not offer any security benefit (unless you send them via a second medium such as SMS or WhatsApp message) you might as well send a single use link.

The final benefit of this is that your non screen reader users do not need to enter a code either so it makes it better for everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You're better off not trying to control this yourself.

When reading generated passwords, activation codes or such, screen reader users are used to pay attention and carefully read character by character, so it shouldn't be a big problem.

IT's even less a problem for screen reader users than it is for partially sighted users, who may have difficulties distinguishing 0, O and o, or 1, I and l.

That's by the way why it is recommended to avoid including 0, O, o, 1, I and l in generated passwords and activation codes.

You'd better don't try to control how it is read yourself because different screen readers have different ways to read such strings and to announce capitals.

For example when reading character by character, in order to distinguish upper from lower case letters, the screen reader may:

- Say the letter with a higher pitch (the most common)
- Say "Capital"
- Produce a sound before or after announcing the letter, for example a small beep

The way screen readers split into words when reading such strings as a whole word is heavily screen reader and voice specific.
Most split at capital boundary, some ignore case, some produce sounds, and it may be customized via screen reader or speech synthesizer options.

So, you're better off not trying to control yourself how such strings are or should be pronounced.

Simply let the users do as they are used to do.

Comment: I think we need to write a guide entitled 'stop trying to make a screen reader talk how you want it to' between us as this seems to be a recurring theme we both end up answering on!